# Change thumb and color of JSlider?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jslider

I am creating a music player program.

I have created the seek bar using `JSlider`

Code:

```
JSlider seek = new JSlider(JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL);  
seek.setOpaque(true);

seek.setMajorTickSpacing(0);
seek.setMinorTickSpacing(0);
 
seek.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
seek.setSize(100, 13);
seek.setLocation(6, 30);
```

Currently, it looks like this :

[image: Seekbar]

I can only change the background of `JSlider` using `setBackground()` method.

I don't have any idea about how to change the thumb colour, thumb shape, track colour, etc.

I want my seek bar to look something like this :

[image: Seek bar with circular thumb and yellow colour]

How can I achieve this?

If not possible with `JSlider`, is it possible to create a `JProgressBar` which has a slidable thumb?

Comment: *I don't have any idea about how to change the thumb colour, thumb shape, track colour, etc.* - that is controlled by the LAF. You would need to customize the U for the JSlider. See the `getUI()` method for the class you are using.

Comment: @camickr I don't understand. The `getUI()` method returns `SliderUI`. But how can I use that to change thumb colour, shape and track colour?

Comment: You look at the methods of the SliderUI to see if there are any methods that allow you to customize those properties. If not, then you need to extend the class and override the appropriate method and do your own custom painting. Or your can check out [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/). It will show some properties used directly by the UI that you might be able to change, but this will change the properties for all sliders in your application.

Comment: Adding to this, is it possible to create a `JProgressBar` which has a slidable thumb?

Comment: A JProgressBar is not designed for that purpose. It is not designed for any user interactgion.  You continue to attempt to use Swing in ways it was not designed to be used.

Comment: @camickr _You continue to attempt to use Swing in ways it was not designed to be used._    Does that suppose to motivate me or demotivate me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As was already mentioned in the comments there is no way for you to change the appearance of the slider without extending an existing implementation of `SliderUI`. Here is an example implementation of how one could achieve the visuals from your demo picture.

Note that hard coding the sizes and colours isn't the best approach and for a real implementation should be handled by setting and using values available by the `UIManager`.

```java
class Scratch {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
            JSlider slider = new JSlider() {
                @Override
                public void updateUI() {
                    setUI(new CustomSliderUI(this));
                }
            };
            content.add(slider);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setContentPane(content);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private static class CustomSliderUI extends BasicSliderUI {

        private static final int TRACK_HEIGHT = 8;
        private static final int TRACK_WIDTH = 8;
        private static final int TRACK_ARC = 5;
        private static final Dimension THUMB_SIZE = new Dimension(20, 20);
        private final RoundRectangle2D.Float trackShape = new RoundRectangle2D.Float();

        public CustomSliderUI(final JSlider b) {
            super(b);
        }

        @Override
        protected void calculateTrackRect() {
            super.calculateTrackRect();
            if (isHorizontal()) {
                trackRect.y = trackRect.y + (trackRect.height - TRACK_HEIGHT) / 2;
                trackRect.height = TRACK_HEIGHT;
            } else {
                trackRect.x = trackRect.x + (trackRect.width - TRACK_WIDTH) / 2;
                trackRect.width = TRACK_WIDTH;
            }
            trackShape.setRoundRect(trackRect.x, trackRect.y, trackRect.width, trackRect.height, TRACK_ARC, TRACK_ARC);
        }

        @Override
        protected void calculateThumbLocation() {
            super.calculateThumbLocation();
            if (isHorizontal()) {
                thumbRect.y = trackRect.y + (trackRect.height - thumbRect.height) / 2;
            } else {
                thumbRect.x = trackRect.x + (trackRect.width - thumbRect.width) / 2;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Dimension getThumbSize() {
            return THUMB_SIZE;
        }

        private boolean isHorizontal() {
            return slider.getOrientation() == JSlider.HORIZONTAL;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(final Graphics g, final JComponent c) {
            ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            super.paint(g, c);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintTrack(final Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            Shape clip = g2.getClip();

            boolean horizontal = isHorizontal();
            boolean inverted = slider.getInverted();

            // Paint shadow.
            g2.setColor(new Color(170, 170 ,170));
            g2.fill(trackShape);

            // Paint track background.
            g2.setColor(new Color(200, 200 ,200));
            g2.setClip(trackShape);
            trackShape.y += 1;
            g2.fill(trackShape);
            trackShape.y = trackRect.y;

            g2.setClip(clip);

            // Paint selected track.
            if (horizontal) {
                boolean ltr = slider.getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight();
                if (ltr) inverted = !inverted;
                int thumbPos = thumbRect.x + thumbRect.width / 2;
                if (inverted) {
                    g2.clipRect(0, 0, thumbPos, slider.getHeight());
                } else {
                    g2.clipRect(thumbPos, 0, slider.getWidth() - thumbPos, slider.getHeight());
                }

            } else {
                int thumbPos = thumbRect.y + thumbRect.height / 2;
                if (inverted) {
                    g2.clipRect(0, 0, slider.getHeight(), thumbPos);
                } else {
                    g2.clipRect(0, thumbPos, slider.getWidth(), slider.getHeight() - thumbPos);
                }
            }
            g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g2.fill(trackShape);
            g2.setClip(clip);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintThumb(final Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(new Color(246, 146, 36));
            g.fillOval(thumbRect.x, thumbRect.y, thumbRect.width, thumbRect.height);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintFocus(final Graphics g) {}
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Custom slider]

Comment: It is perfect. Thank you!